# Can't refresh ListView after AlertDialog has been closed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have a ListView with a button on it.  When I click the Button I have a AlertDialog with a EditText on it that pops up.  When the users enters data into the EditText on the AlertDialog it goes out and updates a SQLite Database.  When the original ListView shows back up it is blank.  When I exit the app and return the app the data entered in the AlertDialog shows up.  I need the new data to show up after the AlertDialog closes.

```
package com.wmason.testcreator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private DbManagement mdbManager;
    private TestProcessor tp;
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lookup);

        mdbManager = new DbManagement(this);
        tp = new TestProcessor(this); 
        mdbManager.open();
        fillData();
        Button testingCsv =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTestCsv);
        testingCsv.setOnClickListener(ChokeSlam);
        fillData();      
    }




    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
        fillData();
    }

    private OnClickListener ChokeSlam = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AssetManager aM = getAssets();

            try{                
                //This line of code opens the AlertDialog
                tp.ProcessInboundStream(aM,"Book1.csv",mdbManager);
                fillData();     
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
              System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }       
    };

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        /*
        boolean b;
        b=mdbManager.deleteTests(id);
        */
        //fillData();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,DisplayTests.class);

        i.putExtra("ID",Long.toString(id));

        startActivity(i);
    }
    private void fillData(){
        Cursor testCursor = mdbManager.fetchAllTests();
        startManagingCursor(testCursor);
        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{DbManagement.Gen_Test_Name};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
//R.layout.
        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.testrows, testCursor, from, to);

        setListAdapter(notes);
        notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They way I figured this out was to use the following method

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    fillData();  
}
```

Basically as soon the AlertDialog closes it fires off this method and it goes out and re-populates the ListView

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: When the users enters data into the EditText on the AlertDialog it goes out. Once your database get updated add this code.

Comment: I just added the code to the original post.  I am not sure if the issue is that I am actually displaying the AlertDialog in a different class called TestProcessor.  Inside that I am actually displaying the AlertDialog and saving the data to the SQLite table.  When I debug the process and I get to the line that says tp.ProcessInboundStream(aM,"Book1.csv",mdbManager); It actually doesn't display the AlertDialog until after the calling method is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this in the Activity file where the dialog is required.

```
AlertDialog dialog = dialogViewer.returnEditDialog();
dialog.show();
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            refreshView();
                        }
                    });
```

The OnDismissListener is called every time an ALertDialog fragment is closed.